# How to list items in a foreach using Tuple.Create by most recent entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using trying to create a Messaging feature on a project that I am using and in order to do that I am using a `foreach` loop through the Model in order to bring in the messages that both the specific user sent and the ones that the specific user has received. I am trying to make it look like a typical messaging service where when you type a message it displays your message and then it also displays the message that was received by you and it does that is chronological order.

My problem is that I can't get it to show the messages by the order of the time. The foreach is showing all the messages but it isn't doing the chronological order part.

Below is my foreach loop:

```
  @{
     var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
     var bob = Model.Chat.Where(u => u.AssignToUserId == user).ToList();
     var sam = Model.Chat.Where(u => u.OwnerUserId == user).ToList();
    }

       @foreach (var message in bob.Zip(sam, Tuple.Create))
                                        {

     <div class="direct-chat-msg">
         <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
    <  span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">@message.Item1.OwnerUser.DisplayName</span>
    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">@message.Item1.Created</span>
  </div>
      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
    <div class="direct-chat-text">
        @message.Item1.Body
    </div>
    <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
    <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
       <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
           <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">@message.Item2.OwnerUser.DisplayName</span>
          <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">@message.Item2.Created</span>
       </div>
         <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->                                               
      <div class="direct-chat-text">
       @message.Item2.Body
      </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
    </div>
   }
```

This is what is being displayed:[Chat Message Windwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu04K.png)

I am trying to get it so that it orders it by date so if I send two messages back to back but only receive one it show my two first and then the other on in proper order and not every other. Thanks!

Comment: Are you telling me you're familiar with `.Zip()` but not `.OrderBy()`? I don't buy it.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to concat the two lists and then order them, not Zip them.  For one Zip will not return all the messages if you don't have the same number in each list.  Second I could type more than one message in a row before there is a response, so zipping wouldn't seem to make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you are probably going to want to use `.OrderBy()` to order your messages and avoid `.Zip()` because you are not guaranteed that you will always get a sender-receiver in pairs. You could get two or more message sent or received in a row.

You are probably going to have to combine your lists somehow and the do some sort of if statement to determine your markup. Something like below should get you close to where you need to be.

```
@{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var bob = Model.Chat.Where(u => u.AssignToUserId == user).ToList();
    var sam = Model.Chat.Where(u => u.OwnerUserId == user).ToList();
    var allMessages = new List<T>();
    allMessages.AddRange(bob).AddRange(sam).OrderBy(x => x.Created);
}

@foreach (var message in allMessages)
{
    @if(message.OwnerUserId == message.OwnerUserId)
    {
        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">@message.Item1.OwnerUser.DisplayName</span>
                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">@message.Item1.Created</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                @message.Item1.Body
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">@message.Item2.OwnerUser.DisplayName</span>
                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">@message.Item2.Created</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->                                               
            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                @message.Item2.Body
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
        </div>
    }
}
```

P.S. Did this in Notepad++ so my markup may not be correct.

Comment: You were extremely helpful in your answer to me. I just had to tweak it a little bit to get it working but you set me on the right path. I had to put everything into one variable so var bob = includes both the owneruserid and assigntouserid and then make it into a list to include bob. Thanks again for your help!